# How to track php functions/codes duration of processing

Tags: php, function, time, process

I am developing a browser based game and i'd like to know which functions take the most time to process and so on.

Does anyone of you guys know what I can start with ? Using PHP 5.3

Comment: the word you're looking for is `profiler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want **[xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof)**.  It excels at profiling.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [profiler in XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

Answer (score 0):

There's also one called [PHP APD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php)